# Reasons of why the signs of the capacitor of the diagram is correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, capacitance, short-circuit, charge

I've written the following diagram.

[image]

The text book says the following.

As the voltage \$V\$ is given between the nodes, it is assumed that the charges \$Q_1,Q_2,Q_3,Q_4,Q_5\$ are charged at each applying capacitor.

My dought came from the diagram.

I can intuitively get the signs of the \$C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4\$ however currently I can't get why the signs of the \$5\$th capacitor is correct of the diagram.

In other expression, why the upper sign  of \$C5\$ is minus and the other is plus, is incorrect.

Can anyone tell me some hint(s) or the website(s) which describe(s) it? so that I can get it in my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively if you start with all the capacitors zero voltage and apply current to Node 1 relative to Node 2 (call that ground) until the voltage at Node 1 is 5V then the polarities will be as shown because C4 > C3 and C1 = C2.

That's because more voltage will be dropped across the smaller capacitance.

The presence of C5 does not change the polarity but it will reduce the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the '+' and '-' are just there for reference -- if the voltage is opposite of the marked values, that just means that you say it's negative.

I.e., in the diagram below, "V" is -1 volt -- and the Schematic Police will not be knocking on my door tonight.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhB6sY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>